# calling different html pages using href

Tags: html, flask

I'm trying to call different HTML pages  through href in   tag after running flask file .But it's giving 
Not found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. where am i going wrong.
` index.html

```
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="button js-button" role="button">
      <i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  File &nbsp; &nbsp;  </a></li>
      <br><br>
      <li><a href="imageupload.html" class="button js-button" role="button"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Image</a></li>
      <br><br>
      <li><a href="addtext.html" class="button js-button" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;  Text &nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

`
app.py

```
 app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'random string'
#app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'templates/'

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<a href="{{ url_for('index.html') }}" class="button js-button" role="button">`

More about templating can be found here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/